# adding a custom calculated field for custom search screens in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, calculated-field

so i have this application where i have to create a simple Search screen based on a query **(this query gets all financial transactions for specified search criteria )**

so what i want is to add a calculated field on the screen that shows **the sum of the search results.** 
not  the sum of all records.

i tried to add a calculated field on the financial transactions table but it doesn't make any sense ..

what should i do in these kind of situations ?

thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you mean by searching, the users entering their criteria in the default search box on a search screen. Remember that the built-in Search is not actually a search on the database but a filter on the query you've already retrieved. So when the user "searches" something, he's actually filtering out rows from the screen, but still are on the underlying data collection bound to the grid.
I'm not aware of any way of intercepting the built-in search box behavior.

One way of implementing what I think you want, is by creating a query and parameterize it by the search criteria required, and building a Search screen around it. You can hide the default search box to make it more clearer.

For example, say that I have a Projects table with an Hours field. First I create a query based on Projects where I add a filter like "Name contains NameParam". Make that param visible on the screen (use this article as a guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/11/09/creating-a-custom-search-screen-in-visual-studio-lightswitch.aspx)
Now I'll use a trick, this is a technique I've seen, I'm not 100% comfortable with it, is based on the fact that, up to now, the Changed event of a text box bound to a query parameter happens after the screen query is executed, but it works on the current version of LS. 
In the designer, select the query parameter (on the left side of the screen), and add code for the "Changed" event. In that event handler, you can then calculate the fields that you'd like. For example, I have this 2 variables (already defined as data items):

```
RecordsCount = ProjectsByName.Count.ToString() 
TotalHours = ProjectsByName.Sum(Function(project) project.Hours)
```

(VB code)
Every time you enter something on the Name text box and hit enter or tab out, the query executes with the new criteria, then the Changed event handler fires and the properties refresh their value.
Something to keep in mind is that for this to work, you should turn off paging. Otherwise it will calculate the results of the current page.
If paging would be required, then you could always execute a second query to get the total results.